# Prove by mathematical induction the following Fibonacci statement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

> Prove by induction: 
>   $$
> f_{n-1}^2 - f_{n-2}^2 = f_n f_{n-3}
> $$
>   where $f_n$ refers to the $n$'th Fibonacci term.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Maybe you could test the claim with some small cases.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you use the fact that $f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$?

Answer (score 3):

Induction is for suckers.  ^_^

$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$  by the definition of the Fibonacci sequence.  Also, $F_{n-1}=F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}$, so $$F_{n-3}=F_{n-1}-F_{n-2}$$ Multiplying those together, we get
$$F_nF_{n-3}=(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})(F_{n-1}-F_{n-2})=F^2_{n-1}-F^2_{n-2}$$